# Pub/sub request authentication as a service (or by service key) instead of Auth0 temporary key

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-authentication, google-cloud-pubsub

Problem Statement :

I want to use REST based requests in google pub/sub(using org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost) for publishing and subscribing to a message, here I have the following request for publishing data to a pub/sub topic (https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/pull)

```
POST https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[project_name]/topics/[topic_id]?key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
```

Here in place of [YOUR_API_KEY] I put the api key from 
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials 
which give the response as unauthorized

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "User not authorized to perform this action.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

and If I add the access token fetched from the following command

```
gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
```

the token is valid only for a limited duration of 60 minutes.
Due to which I have to create a access_token every hour.

**Since this is a server to server request I want request to be authorized for longer duration until without any external interference.**

Can anyone please suggest or point out any mistakes. Thank you in advance

Comment: Pub/Sub does not support API keys for authorization. Are you trying to authorize Pub/Sub to call your service (HTTP endpoint)? Your question is not clear. `print-access-token` is for testing and not for real usage. Normally you assign a service account that Pub/Sub uses for identity based authorization to the called endpoint as the HTTP `Authorization` header. Edit your question to clarify what you have configured.

Comment: thanks you @John, I am trying to push the message to a topic. Here I have a service account. But I have to use rest-based apis for publishing message since i have to check the server status and then pull optimal no. of messages for publishing. Here the request responds with 403 if only api key is provided.

Is it that i have to create a auth with the api key created where I can specify the expiry time.
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#jwt-auth

Comment: Edit your question with the new details. Remember, there is no API key to use. You must use a service account.

Answer (score 1):

In your use case a production server to server communication when using a 
Google Cloud Platform client library. The best approach to authentication is to use a strategy called Application Default Credentials (ADC) to find your application's credentials.

If using a client library,the strategy checks for your credentials in the following order:

1) ADC checks to see if the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is set. If the variable is set, ADC uses the service account file that the variable points to.

2) If the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable is not set, ADC uses the default service account that Compute Engine, Kubernetes Engine, Cloud Run, App Engine, and Cloud Functions provide, for applications that run on those services.

3) If ADC can't use either of the above credentials, an error occurs.

For a comprehensive explanation you should review the official documentation [Setting Up Authentication for Server to Server Production Applications](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production)

Comment: Hi @Paddy thanks for your reply. But here I am using org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost . where there is no automatic authentication or google code that looks for the environment variable. I am using simple HttpPost since we wanted to have a controlled flow of data. Please correct me I have misinterpreted anything.

Comment: Then you need to use a Bearer Token for authentication in the HTTP request header